# Join data from multiple tables into SelectList, and precede each dataset with a caption in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So this is a bit more complex than what I've been trying to do in the past. Essentially I have a few different tables: `employee.employees`, `companies.employees`, `dbo.all_employees`, and `companies`. They are represented by the following models, in order: `employees1`, `employees`, `all_employees`, and `companies`.

`all_employees` has 3 columns `all_id`, `employee_id`, and `employee_type`. I'm attempting to make a SelectList to populate a drop drop list, that will house all of the employees divided by their appropriate company. I've managed to get all the employees by name into the combo box, but I can't seem to figure out how separate the employees.

So think of it like this. If `all_employees` has a record with an `employee_type` of 1, they belong to our company, and their first and last name should be pulled from `employees1`, if they have anything other than an `employee_type` of 1 then they belong to another company, and should be pulled from `employees`

Here is my rough code that currently pulls all the employees from both tables, unions them, and places them into a select list. I simply need to figure out how to easily split them up so it looks something like

```
-- Select Employee --
-- Company 1
   First Last
   First Last
-- Company 2
   First Last
-- Company 3
   First Last
```

Code

```
        var query1 = from c in _db.employees1
                join p in _db.all_employees on c.employee_id equals p.employee_id into ps
                select new { employee_id = c.employee_id, name = c.first_name + " " + c.last_name };
        var query2 = from c in _db.employees
                join p in _db.all_employees on c.employee_id equals p.employee_id into ps
                select new { employee_id = c.employee_id, name = c.first_name + " " + c.last_name };
        var merged = query2.Union(query1);
        ViewBag.employeeid = new SelectList(merged, "employee_id", "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a possible solution in the form of a third party extension. It implements optgroup, and allows me to to easily control everything. I think this is the best solution but  I'm not entirely sure.

The library is [here](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/01/html5-dropdownlist-optgroup-tag-in-mvc.html).

And my modified code now looks similar to this:

Controller:

```
        var query1 = from c in _db.employees1
                join p in _db.all_employees on c.employee_id equals p.employee_id into ps
                select new { employee_id = c.employee_id, name = c.first_name + " " + c.last_name, companyID = 1, company = "LightHouse Electric" };
        var query2 = from c in _db.employees
                join p in _db.all_employees on c.employee_id equals p.employee_id into ps
                select new { employee_id = c.employee_id, name = c.first_name + " " + c.last_name, companyID = c.company_id, company = "Other" };

        var merged = query2.Union(query1);

        var data = merged.ToList().Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem {
            GroupKey = t.companyID.ToString(),
            GroupName = t.company,
            Text = t.name,
            Value = t.employee_id.ToString()
        });
        ViewBag.employeeid = data;
```

View:

```
            @Html.DropDownGroupListFor(model => Model.employee_id, (IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem>)ViewBag.employeeid,
                "-- Select --", new {@data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "The Name field is required.", @class="form-control"})
```